# How to read spring boot application property information inside the library

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am developing a common library for our projects. It is a maven project.  Now It does not have any dependency related to Spring.

I am including the above library in the Spring boot maven project as a dependency.

As Spring Boot application runs, I need to read the value from Spring boot application.properties inside the common library.

Assume that I have environment key inside the application.properties.

environment = STAGE

I need the value of the environment inside the library.

Comment: I might suggest creating a wrapper module which is spring aware (maybe a spring boot auto configuration). That way your library is spring independent but maybe accepts a configuration value programmatically, and your spring module automatically picks up the spring property. I think the last thing you want is for the library itself to read from application.properties directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest, you should add provision in your library to accept external configurations. You can create a `Configuration` class in your library which will store all required properties. Then you can create an instance of `Configuration` and provide it to other classes in your library. I see many libraries follows same pattern. Let's take example of Elasticsearch client which requires Elasticsearch URL:

**Elasticsearch client**

```
String elasticsearchUrl = environment.getRequiredProperty("elasticsearch-url");

ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration =
    ClientConfiguration.builder().connectedTo(elasticsearchUrl).build();
RestHighLevelClient client = RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
```

In above example `elasticsearch-url` is accepted through `application.properties` file and then provided to Elasticsearch client library.

Answer (score 1):

In the Spring Boot Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
```

public class ExampleMsApplication implements ApplicationRunner {

```
@Value("${props.env}")
private String env;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ExampleMsApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("env", env);
}
```

}

**application.properties**

props.env=local

**In the library** wherever its required, i am using the below code. Whatever i set in the spring boot application using **System.setProperty** , i am able to get using **System.getProperty**

System.getProperty("env")

Answer (score 0):

You can create a @ConfigurationProperties class and create /resources/META-INF/spring.factories file with following property:-

org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=Full classified name of your class